# Google Contacts access with Service Account json c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, oauth-2.0, google-contacts-api

I'm trying to access my Google Contacts using OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications in a ASP.net MVC application but I'm having some troubles trying to retrieve the token. "test-470272c3a5fa.json" is the file I downloaded from google api console and is currently on my desktop. Any idea?

Here is my code:

```
public class GoogleContactsApiInterface
{
    public GoogleContactsApiInterface()
    {
        ServiceAccountCredential serviceAccountCredential;
        string[] scopes = { "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/" };
        string keyPath = "C:\\Users\\55122545\\Desktop\\test-470272c3a5fa.json";

        using (var stream = new FileStream(keyPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            serviceAccountCredential =  GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream)
                                                        .CreateScoped(scopes)
                                                        .UnderlyingCredential as ServiceAccountCredential;

            OAuth2Parameters parameters = new OAuth2Parameters();
            parameters.AccessToken  = serviceAccountCredential.Token.AccessToken;
            parameters.RefreshToken = serviceAccountCredential.Token.RefreshToken;

            RequestSettings rs = new RequestSettings("testApp", parameters);
            rs.AutoPaging = true;

            ContactsRequest cr = new ContactsRequest(rs);

            Feed<Contact> f = cr.GetContacts();

            foreach (Contact c in f.Entries)
            {
                //do something
            }

        }
    }
}
```